Hyper-V. Не удалось получить доступ к классу WMI
Мне нужно установить Ubuntu через Hyper-V с графическим интерфейсом. Сам Hyper-V установлен через компоненты. В инструкциях были варианты установки и настройки через Windows Server (Диспетчер серверов), его найти не удалось.
Далее по инструкции в самом Hyper-V необходимо нажать на кнопку "Создать", чтобы добавить виртуальную машину, а такой опции у меня нет, потому что нет хоста(?), который автоматически добавляется у других пользователей Hyper-V.
Уже добавлены рекомендуемые исключения, однако из папок в исключения добавлена только С:\Program Files\Hyper-V. Других папок из рекомендуемого списка нет. Не помогло.

При попытке подключения к локальному компьютеру возникает следующая ошибка:

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему.

Такая же ситуация сейчас была. Мне помогло следующее действие :
Компоненты windows   Платформа Hyper V -> Службы Hyper V (отметить чек-бокс)
Ну и в результате скачивания  ребутнуть комп
